# Put JSON Data In View Codeiginiter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter. I want to put JSON data from controller to view in CodeIgniter. So far, I can show the JSON data directly from my controller.

Here is my code for controller:

```
public function index()
{
    //$this->load->view('test');
    $get_url_service = $this->url_service->GetUrl('KategoriRetrieve');
    $get_json = file_get_contents($get_url_service);
    $get_data = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($get_json, TRUE)), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    //print_r ($get_data);
    foreach ($get_data as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val))
            echo "$key:"."<br />";
        else
            echo "$key => $val"."<br />";
    }
}
```

The function `GetUrl()` is loaded from my custom library called url_service. Here is my library url_service.php

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

    class Url_service
    {
        public function GetUrl($param){
        //http://localhost:90/Aset/json/reply/
        return "http://localhost:90/kugi_deployment/api/json/reply/".$param;
        }
    }
```

Like I already said above, I want to show the data in view. How can I do that? Can anyone help me to do this? Thanks

Comment: instead on foreach, use `json_encode($get_data)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data to the view from the controller.

controller:

```
...
$data['get_data'] = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($get_json, TRUE)), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$this->load->view('myview', $data);
...
```

view (in myview.php it in view directory):

```
<?php

foreach ($get_data as $key => $val) {
....
}

?>
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: I see. My bad did not realize that the JSON data has been converted to multidimensional array. Thanks anyway bro @Jackie